# reverse printing

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm working on a looping program that prints a series of numbers. I wonder how i do the reverse of this such that the output would be like

```
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

My program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    //Local Declarations
    int limit;
    //Statements
    for (int lineCtrl = 1; lineCtrl <= 9; lineCtrl++)
    {
        for (int numCtrl = 1;
                 numCtrl <= lineCtrl;
                 numCtrl++)
        printf("%1d", numCtrl);
    printf("\n");
    }
    //to exit the program
    int temp;
    printf("Enter an integer and press Enter to exit the program: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are asking this, you don't understand how your own program works.

Comment: if this is homework, you should tell us so

Comment: How did you manage to write that code if you don't know what it does? I'm calling your mother, young man. (Take heed. I am the living echo of trutheality)

Answer (score 2):

The only line changed is the first for loop initialization:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    //Local Declarations
    int limit;
    //Statements
    for (int lineCtrl = 9; lineCtrl >= 1; lineCtrl--)
    {
        for (int numCtrl = 1;
                 numCtrl <= lineCtrl;
                 numCtrl++)
        printf("%1d", numCtrl);
    printf("\n");
    }
    //to exit the program
    int temp;
    printf("Enter an integer and press Enter to exit the program: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    return 0;
}
```